# Какой знак надо поставить?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть вопросы, волнующие людей. И их немало. Среди тех, что требуют внимания со стороны властей(?) выделение земель под строительство...
Какой знак надо поставить в скобках (хочется тире, а автор поставил запятую)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна и запятая, и тире. Ставятся они по разным основаниям. Запятая необходима для того, чтобы закрыть оборот "что". Он должен быть закрыт независимо от того, будет ли дальше тире, либо слово. Вы можете продолжать предложение чем хотите, то обязаны закрыть все обороты с обеих сторон (кроме исключительных случаев, например, когда в начале предложения есть короткий деепричастный оборот. Тогда запятую там в справочниках опускают и оставляют тире. Но это особый случай). Тире же заменяет подразумеваемый глагол, имеющий значение вроде "находится". Тире, само собой, тоже должно быть поставлено независимо от того, будет перед ним запятая, либо не будет. Ещё раз подчеркну: знаки ставятся по разным основаниям, а потому нужны оба.

Answer (score 2):

Есть вопросы, волнующие людей. И их немало. ***Среди тех, что требуют внимания со стороны властей(?) выделение земель под строительство...***

Можно ли однозначно расставить знаки препинания в предложении, которое приведено не полностью? Я полагаю, что нет (иногда это даже без контекста трудно сделать).

Я попробую закончить предложение следующим образом: ***Среди тех, что требуют внимания со стороны властей, выделение земель под строительство является наиболее важным вопросом.***

Ну и где здесь тире? Нет здесь тире, только запятая.

**И вывод:** Уважаемые авторы вопросов! Пожалуйста, всегда приводите полный текст предложения.